# Updating room database by using Object

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I am using Room databse in android and I want to update it by using object.

I want to do this. Is it possible?
`

```
@Query("UPDATE video_info_table SET videoStatus = :model.videoStatus WHERE id = :model.id")
fun delete(model: FileModelClass)
```

`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No** (not directly), you should use either:-

```
@Update
fun update(model: FileModelClass)
```

- and obviously set ALL the fields/members correctly (as all fields bar the primary key, which is used for the where clause, will be updated)

OR

```
@Query("UPDATE video_info_table SET videoStatus = :videoStatus WHERE id = :id")
fun update(videoStatus: String, id: Long)
```

- when calling then use `thedao.update(theFileModelClass.videoStatus,theFileModel.id)`
- note that the types may have to be changed to suit the actual fields/members (e.g. perhaps `Int` instead of `Long`)

Of course you could have a wrapper for the second in the interface *and thus yes to the question but indirectly*, such as

```
fun update(model: FileModelClass) {
    update(model.videoStatus, model.id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
@Query("UPDATE video_info_table SET videoStatus =:status WHERE id = :id")
void update(String status, int id);
```